# Update Interactive Card in Google Hangout to disable Button

Tags: google-hangouts

Please let me know how to update the Interactive Card in Google Hangout to disable action Button.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can have a better idea on how to structure your question

Comment: Disable option is not feasible currently - try timing out the widget, means after x min if user clicks on a widget then give an error in the same widget.